# Azure deployment for QnA service fails in portal - invalid template

Tags: azure, azureportal, azure-qna-maker

I'm trying to deploy Azure QnA service via Azure portal. When I populate all fields and start deployment it fails with the following message:

The template deployment 'Microsoft.CognitiveServicesQnAMaker' is not valid according to the validation procedure. The tracking id is '....'. See inner errors for details. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-deploy for usage details.

Answer (score 0):

If you have deployed the resource from a *custom template* or from a *template saved to your account* that is similar to the procedure shown here -> (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-template-deploy-portal) and if you are receiving an *invalid template deployment error according to validation procedure* then you can follow below steps to resolve the issue. Hope this helps!

1. Get Correlation ID of the deployment operation event by following the steps that are illustrated here -> (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-manager-deployment-operations)
2. Run the command *Get-AzureRMLog -CorrelationId xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx -DetailedOutput* to see if the output of it has any specific information regarding the root cause of the issue.
3. Find the exact error code and validate it here -> (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-manager-common-deployment-errors). For example, if your error code is *InvalidTemplate* then check *your template syntax for errors* and follow this (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-manager-invalid-template-errors) link to resolve invalid template error.